# What is the complexity / name of word search problem in linear groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

This is a question about a search problem associated with [user6976's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80542/the-complexity-of-the-word-problem-in-linear-groups). Suppose we are given a finite set of elements $S \subset \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ containing inverses of all its elements, and an integer $L$, and are asked to find a list of primitive non-redundant relationships of the form $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_{L'} = 1$ with $L' \leq L$. Here $a_1 a_2 \cdots a_{L'} = 1$ is primitive if no subproduct $a_l a_{l+1} \cdots a_{l'}$ of the l.h.s. evaluates to identity, and redundant if a cyclic permutation of it or its inverse is already in the list.

Of course, to fully specify the problem we must agree on how many such relationships should be in the list. We might ask for all of them (let say there are $m_L$ such relationships) or for a positive fraction of them: $\left\lfloor \rho m_L \right\rfloor$ relationships for some fixed $\rho \in (0, 1)$.

What is known about the complexity of this problem? In particular, can it be solved in the time polynomial in $L$, the size of the input, and $m_L$? Or, at least, (for a fixed $S$ and $\rho$) is there an upper bound better than $o\!\left(Lm_{L} + \left(\left|S\right|-1\right)^{L/2}\right)$? Are there any practical algorithms for solving it (better than brute-force)?

---

Note: similarly to [user6976's question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80542/the-complexity-of-the-word-problem-in-linear-groups), $\mathbb{Q}$ can be replaced with any field of characteristic 0 by, possibly, moving to larger matrix sizes: e.g. $\sqrt{q}$ can be represented as $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\q&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ by doubling the matrix size; see also [(Lipton, Zalcstein)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/322017.322031) for the proof of logspace complexity of the original word problem.

Note 2: By brute force, in this context, I mean an algorithm going the breadth-first-search on products of length up to $L/2$, discarding all non-primitive products and writing the rest into a hash table, with complexity scaling with $L$ roughly as $\left(\left|S\right|-1\right)^{L/2}$ (but could be slightly better if a lot of products are discarded as non-primitive).

Comment: Perhaps this keyword is useful: you are asking about the *word problem* in the group $G$ generated by $S$. This is usually phrased as determining if a single word represents a non-trivial element, but you are asking how long it will take to construct the entire ball of radius $L/2$ in the Cayley graph.

Comment: @HJRW Thank you! Yes, the word problem is a decision problem, and I'm interested in a related search problem. Yes, effectively I'm looking for a problem of computing a description of the ball of radius $L/2$ in the Cayley graph (specifically, description in terms of simple cycles passing through the origin).

Comment: If you want to actually build the ball of radius $R$, then the output will typically be exponential in $R$.  So the running time can't be faster than that (and it probably will be about that, up to changing the base of the exponential a bit).  If you want a "description of the ball of radius $R$" then you need to say what you mean by "description".

Comment: One possible (very weak) "description" might be "give a finite presentation" for the group generated by $S$.  However, a quick google search suggests that $\mathrm{SL}(d, \mathbb{Z})$ is not coherent, so this does not work... I think?

Comment: I would guess this can be done in polynomial space since the word problem is logspace but you are doing exponentially many words.

Comment: @SamNead: it’s worse than that. Even if I promise you that a matrix group $G$ is finitely presented, then there is no algorithm that computes a presentation for $G$. (At least, not one that is uniform in the rank $n$.)

Comment: @SamNead Note: $d \geq 4$ indeed $\operatorname{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$ is indeed not coherent (by embedding Mikhailova’s group $F_2 \times F_2$ by doubling the Sanov matrices). For $d=2$ it is obviously coherent, and for $d=3$ we don’t know. So as HJRW suggests there’s really no chance to do it even for quite small $d$.

Comment: Whether the number of such simple cycles is exponential depends on $S$: e.g. if group $G$ generated by $S$ is finite, then the number of simple cycles is finite. If $G$ is free with half of the $S$ (picking one element from every pair $\{s,s^{-1}\}$) as generators, then the number of simple cycles is also finite (they are all of the form $ss^{-1}=1$). So there are examples where $m_L$ does not grow exponentially with $L$. Even if $m_L$ grows exponentially, it can be much slower than $(\left|S\right|-1)^{L/2}$, so the complexity question is still non-trivial in that case.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yes, if you stream out the answer you can do it in $L \left\lceil\log_2(\left|S\right|)\right\rceil + O(\log(\left|S\right| L)) + \Delta$ space, where $\Delta$ is the space for checking a single word: just go over all $(\left|S\right|^{L+1} - 1)/(\left|S\right|-1)$ possible words in depth first search order, checking that the suffices are non-trivial when you do so (if suffix evaluates to 1, abandon the branch), and check the represenative is canonical before outputting words which evaluate to 1.